# Облако тегов

Tags: html, css, javascript

Вот, к примеру, на любой cms есть блок - как правило, правый сайдебар, в него ложат все тэги сайта,  но как реализуется то, чтобы эти слова помещались целиком либо переносились целиком? 
Я пробовал это реализовать, задавая как самому тегу `<p> , <span>`, так и родительскому блоку свойства:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
word-wrap:break-all;
word-break:break-all;
```

И это не помогало, наверное, что-то требуется дополнительно?

Comment: @maximсka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы имеете в виду, чтобы длинные слова переносились, то все правильно:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xq5xmnx2/)

---

**UPD 1.** О, дошло , что вы хотите. Используйте свойство `white-space: nowrap;`

Пример:

```css
.tags {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
.tags a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
    <a href="#">Супер тег</a>
    <a href="#">Еще один тег</a>
    <a href="#">И еще тег</a>
    <a href="#">Классный тег</a>
    <a href="#">Вот тег последний</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Нее оно только стало в ряд и при добавлении  новых тегов блок убежал -- так не пойдёт

Comment: как это блок убежал?) Объясните подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Все слова встали в ряд, а блок маленький 200рх, и они в ряд встали и стали шыре, чем сам блок, и вниз ушли. Я понимаю, что можно задать overflow, но это не выход, мне нужен перенос слов, сдесь я не могу понять, почему свойство не работает, как и у вас, так и у меня.

Comment: так вы добавляйте white-space: nowrap; к каждому слову, а не ко всему блоку

Comment: так она и так фиксированная

Comment: @maximсka боюсь, я вас не понимаю)) Что насчет скриншота того, что вам нужно и что у ввас есть?

Comment: есть такая штука как BLOCK, через него пробуйте